# Error al guardar mi reporte hecho en JasperReports en Java

Tags: java, eclipse, jasper-reports

*Hola comunidad, he realizado un reporte con jasperReport y lo vinculado con mi aplicación java, al momento de dar clic al botón que va ejecutar el reporte lo hace bien, me sale mi reporte hecho en JasperReport y me lo visualiza desde mi aplicación Java pero al momento de darle guardar el documento en formato pdf en la parte inferior de mi IDE eclipse me sale un error y al ir a ver el documento pdf de mi reporte, abro el archivo pero me sale que el documento esta dañado, paso mi código java y el código que me aparece en la parte superior en mi eclipse:*

**CÓDIGO JAVA**

```
package semana_13.reportes;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JDialog;


import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewer;
import semana_13.util.Conexion;

public class ReporteDocentes extends JDialog {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ReporteDocentes dialog = new ReporteDocentes("");
                    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    dialog.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public ReporteDocentes(String valor) {
        setBounds(100, 100, 880, 700);
        //setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        String ruta="D:\\Irbin\\PROGRAMACIÓN\\IDAT\\III CICLO\\DESARROLLO AVANZADO DE APLICACIONES I\\PRACTICAS\\Reports\\MyReports\\ReporteDocentes.jasper";
        Connection cn=null;
        try {
            cn=Conexion.getConexion();
            Map parametro=new HashMap();
            parametro.put("nombre",valor);
            JasperReport reporte=(JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(ruta);
            JasperPrint jp=JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte,parametro,cn);
            getContentPane().add(new JRViewer(jp));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**CÓDIGO ERROR EN JAVA**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/DocumentException
    at net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.classic.ClassicPdfProducerFactory.createProducer(ClassicPdfProducerFactory.java:44)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.createPdfProducer(JRPdfExporter.java:808)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.initExport(JRPdfExporter.java:704)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:665)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.view.save.JRPdfSaveContributor.save(JRPdfSaveContributor.java:113)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewerToolbar.btnSaveActionPerformed(JRViewerToolbar.java:422)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewerToolbar$1.actionPerformed(JRViewerToolbar.java:138)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 44 more
```

*Ese el error que me aparece al tratar de guardar mi reporte en pdf.*

Comment: Noclassdeffound significa que falta poner en el classpath la librería que usa para serializar, itext parece ser

Comment: como agrego eso en el codigo

Comment: Eso va es en la forma como corres el código. El classpath es lo que usa la JVM para cargar las clases que necesitas. Revisa en la configuración de ejecución en eclipse para ese proyecto

Comment: A mi me pasa lo mismo pero en neatbeans me da la excepción Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.itextpdf.text.Document.setRole(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName)'

Comment: @FreddyPeralta revisa [las dependencias](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/) que corresponden a tu versión de JasperReports.

Comment: Hola Freddy, si la porpuesta de padaleiana, no te soluciona el problema, te sugiero que hagas una nueva pregunta, antes mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.